# Virtualization not enabled in Windows 8, but enabled in BIOS

Tags: windows-8, lenovo-laptop, intel-core-i7, hardware-virtualization

I have an i7-2640M processor in a Lenovo T520 laptop with the latest bios. Virtualization is enabled in the bios, and Hyper-V is enabled in Windows 8. Intels CPU tool and Speccy still report that virtualization isn't enabled. (I'm trying to install HAXM)

Any idea what might be wrong here?

EDIT: Screenshots:

[image: Hyper-V Enabled]

[image: Speccy - Virtualization Not Supported]

Comment: If Hyper-V is enabled then the required. virtualization is enabled post a screenshot of Speccy that indicates otherwise

Comment: @Ramhound: Added screenshots

Comment: HAXM does not work with Hyper-V.

Comment: @ta.speot.is: Could you elaborate? What do I need to do to enable virtualization?

Comment: Uninstall Hyper-V

Comment: Speccy does not indicate which virtualization is not supported.  Verify your CPU supports the virualization your attempting to enable.  There are multiple virtuatiization features that exist in Intel and AMD CPUs currently.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If one were to [read the installation instructions](http://software.intel.com/en-us/articles/installation-instructions-for-intel-hardware-accelerated-execution-manager-microsoft) one would find:

> If performance issues are seen on Windows 8 it is recommended to disable Hyper-V.

If one were to read [anecdotes](http://forums.ouya.tv/discussion/82/windows-8-how-to-install-intel-haxm-after-installing-hyper-v) on the Internet, then one would find that [HAXM and Hyper-V are mutually exclusive](http://software.intel.com/en-us/forums/topic/328242).

> Hyper-V on Windows 8 prevents the installation, execution of many other virtualization technologies such as HAXM

and

> The best thing you can do to get HAXM detect VT again, is turning the whole Hyper-V "Feature" off.

From my own experiences, you cannot install HAXM if Hyper-V is enabled.